# Filter the NASDAQ stocks for investment

Tags: portfolio-optimization, trading, investment

I manage an investment portfolio since 3 years now. It might be interesting to filter all  the NASDAQ stocks to tell us which ones have the greatest profit potential.

Is there an arxiv or whatever paper which can help me filtering the NASDAQ stock? Be aware that I am a senior python programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure about papers, but it seems you are looking for a `stock screener`, which these two are my favorites, that you can filter stocks based on your parameters (e.g., ROI, ROE, net profit, debt, market cap, volatility, etc.):

[TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/screener/)

[Finviz](https://finviz.com/screener.ashx)